# How can I analyze .pcd files with abnormal structures?

Tags: python, analysis, point-clouds

First things first, I am new to Python and programming in general so bear with me.

For a college project I have been tasked with carrying out analysis on .pcd files captured during 3D printing using laser beam powder bed fusion. Due to the layer by layer nature of this printing process my .pcd files are in the format [x,y,z,z] with x and y being plane coords and z being TEMPERATURE (not z plane coords!!!). The pyrometer within the 3D printer measures the temperature twice for some reason, leading to the [x,y,z,z] structure.

I have not been able to find any similar examples online. I am trying to analyze these files to find heat correlations and relationships. I have tried Python, Open3d, CloudCompare, Meshlab, etc. but the root problem appears to be the abnormal structure of the files. No software can read them.

For additional context the .pcd files I am working with are individual layers of the point cloud in the z plane dimension (separate file for each layer). They DO NOT have the initial structure typical of .pcd files (seen below), and of course are in the format [x,y,z,z] z being temperature twice.

```
# .PCD v.5 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION .5
FIELDS x y z
SIZE 4 4 4
TYPE F F F
COUNT 1 1 1
WIDTH 397
HEIGHT 1
POINTS 397
DATA ascii/binary
```

If I have not been clear enough I can provide as much data as I can but unfortunately cannot upload the full .pcd files due to GDPR reasons.

As mentioned, I have tried many different software's to read my files but would be happiest if I could read and analyze them on Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your description says that the z coordinate appears twice, but your file header says `FIELDS x y z`. Have you tried just changing that header line to `FIELDS x y z w` and then just ignore the w coordinate?

Comment: Or maybe call the temperature `t` instead of `z` so as to not confuse libraries that think `z` always means a third spatial coordinate.